Deploying GAE Node-JS app using gcloud app deploy fails at build step 2
I have recently updated the node-js version from 4.x to 20.15.1
In the package.json I use this as the engine :
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.15.1"
  },

Now when I use gcloud app deploy the build always fails with this error :
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
In the app.yaml I describe it as :
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

This was all working perfectly until I moved to the later version of Node.

My original app.yaml didn't include the
runtime_config:
  operating_system: ubuntu22

This wasn't required before. Once this was included, the application was deployed as usual.
